# How specialized are the Stream implementations returned by the standard collections?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

[`Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) is an interface so whenever one gets hold of a `Stream` object there are lots of implementation specific details hidden.

For example, take the following code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
...
int size = list.stream()
               .count();
```

Does it run in constant or linear time? Or this:

```
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
...
set.stream()
   .sorted()
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Would that be O(n) or O(n log n)?

In general, how specialized are the streams implementations returned by the standard collections?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Does it run in constant or linear time?

The current implementation runs in linear time:

```
public final long count() {
    return mapToLong(e -> 1L).sum();
}
```

But, this could be improved (there's an RFE for this somewhere) to run in constant time *in some situations*.

How?  A stream is described by a *stream source*, zero or more *intermediate operations*, and a *terminal operation* (here, `count()` is the terminal operation).  The stream implementation maintains a set of characteristics about the source, and knows how the characteristics are modified by the operations.  For example, a stream backed by a Collection has the characteristic `SIZED`, whereas a stream backed by an Iterator is not sized.  Similarly, the operation `map()` is size-preserving, but the operation `filter()` destroys any a priori knowledge of sized-ness.  The stream implementation knows the composed characteristics of the pipeline before it starts the terminal operation, so it knows whether the source is sized and whether all stages are size-preserving, and in such cases, could simply ask the source for the size and bypass all the actual stream computation.  (But the implementation in Java 8 does not happen to do this.)

Note that the streams need not be specialized to support this; the Collection classes create the stream with a `Spliterator` that knows its characteristics, so a specialized implementation for Collections is not needed, just updating the shared implementation to take advantage of this particular bit of information.

Comment: You didn’t answer the `sorted()` part. I found out that it skips sorting for a `null` comparator (like the question’s code uses) but doesn’t skip for any non-`null` comparator, even if the `TreeSet` and the `sorted(…)` call refer to the same comparator instance (not to speak about recognizing that `null` and `Comparator.naturalOrder()` are equivalent). And that’s while the example uses `forEach` which is explicitly defined to be unordered so sorting could be skipped regardless of the actual comparators…

Comment: @Holger: Right, one of the characteristics we track is "sorted in natural order", which a treeset with no explicit comparator is known to be; in the second example, the current implementation is O(n).

Answer (score 2):

The `sorted()` method does not change the size, so it would, in theory, be possible that a future implementation could do a chain of `stream().sorted().count()` in `O(1)` time.

Take a look at the [speedment] open source implementation of the Stream interface at https://github.com/speedment/speedment. These streams can introspect their own pipeline and optimize away one or several steps in the stream.